# Deallocating memory from a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to delete the n'th element, which is a random number from 1 to n.
My code does this fine (correct element is deleted and surrounding elemnts are connected) but when it comes to being efficient, it is crashing when I un-comment the line `delete (nodeToRemove);` and I'm not sure why. Does anyone have any insight?

Assuming my struct looks like :

```
    struct Node {
      int data;        // The data being stored at the node
      Node *next;     // Pointer to the next node
      };



    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void deleteNthElement (Node * & head, Node * &temp, int random)
      {
      temp = head;
      Node *nodeToRemove;

      if (random == 1)
          {
          nodeToRemove = temp;
          head = head->next;
          }

      else
          {
          for (int i = 1; i < random - 1; i++)
            temp = temp->next;

          nodeToRemove = temp->next;
          temp->next = temp->next->next;
          }

     // delete (nodeToRemove); <----- uncommenting this leads to crash, 
      }//end deleteNthElement()

    //------------------------------------------
    int main()
    {

  Node *head = NULL;
  Node *temp;
     Node *listarray[n[i]];


  int n[] = {1000, 5000, 9000, 105000, 400000, 500000, 505000, 800000, 995000, 1000000};

          for (int j = 0; j < n[i]; j++)
            listarray[j] = new (Node);

          //start timer
          begin = clock();

          //fill it
          for (int j = 0; j < n[i]; j++)
              {
              listarray[j]->data = (rand() % n[i] + 1);
              insertNodeInOrder (head, temp, listarray[j]);
              }

          //delete it
          for (int j = 0; j < n[i]; j++)
            deleteNthElement (head, temp, (rand() % (n[i] - j) + 1));

          //deallocate
          for (int j = 0; j < n[i]; j++)
            delete listarray[j];

          delete *listarray;

//end timer
        }
```

Comment: have you debbuged it?

Comment: You don't show any `new` or `delete` code, so we don't know much here. But this looks more like C code than C++.

Comment: Show more code... i.e How you are creating/inserting list.

Comment: Check how nodes were allocated, note each delete can be done for some memory if that was allocated through new

Comment: Initialize your pointers to NULL values, then before `delete (nodeToRemove)` add `std::assert(nodeToRemove!=NULL)`, debugger should allow you to step into code to see program state and whats wrong with it.

Comment: Edited original post to show the new call. I delete in main because I'm supposed to delete each array positions node, and after that delete the array of node* itself.

Comment: The crash depends on two functions: `insertNodeInOrder` (presumably allocating the head with `head = new node(???);` and `deleteNthElement`. If `insertNodeInOrder` does not allocate each element with `new` (for example, if it fills the nodes by taking them from the passed in `listArray`) then your application will crash.

Comment: What are the purposes of the `n` and `listarray` arrays? You *can* implement a linked list in an array, but is that what you're trying to do? (BTW: `delete *listarray;` is equivalent to `delete listarray[0];` - it doesn't delete `listarray`, and you *shouldn't* delete `listarray` because it's not dynamically allocated).

Comment: `deleteNthElement()` was pretty sane. I'm having trouble figuring out what is going on in `main()` (rhyme not intended) what is `n` before `int n[]`? what is `i`? where is the memory for `listarray` allocated? (it is pointer to array)

Answer (score 1):

At least, you have to check for the end of the list, that is, you need to avoid access to null pointers (i really hope you set next to 0 at the end of the list). If you add the allocation parts, I will extend my answer.

```
void deleteNthElement (Node * & head, Node * &temp, int random)
{
    temp = head;
    Node *nodeToRemove;

    if (random == 1)
    {
        nodeToRemove = temp;
        if(head != 0)
            head = head->next;

    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i < random - 1; i++)
            if(temp != 0)
                temp = temp->next;
            else throw 1;   // no such index; throw something more verbose :)

        if(temp == 0)
            throw 1;        // same situation as above

        nodeToRemove = temp->next;
        if(nodeToRemove == 0)
            throw 1;        // same situation as above

        temp->next = temp->next->next;
     }
    if(nodeToRemove == 0)
        throw 1; //no such index; ... as the above 3

    delete nodeToRemove;
}//end deleteNthElement()
```

Comment: -just added allocation parts

Comment: Still not complete enough to have sufficient sight. Also, it looks  a bit messy, hard to figure out what's going on. You should at least add the code for insertNodeInOrder.

Answer (score 1):

You're picking the wrong `Node`, you want:

```
 ...
 nodeToRemove = temp;
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Some clean-up first:

Why pass in two pointers here? do you need the value of temp out? If so why not return it?
Also why the `node * & temp`? (I can see why it is done for `head`).
`int random` should probably be called something like `index` as it describes the functionality better (as far as the function is concerned, there is nothing random about it).
The same with `temp`.

I propose:

```
void delete_element (Node* &head, int index)
{
    Node* parent_node = head;
    Node* node_to_remove;
    //...
```

We don't need temp if we are removing the head. Also, we generally `0` index things, so we should reflect that too. Thus it becomes:

```
if (index== 0)
{
    node_to_remove= head;
    head = head->next;
}
```

Now we get to the main bit.  The loop is just there to step through to the parent node of the node to delete, so we can simplify it a little and add checks to make sure we can't 'fall off' the end of the list.
We then have to make sure there is a node to remove, (so another check). We don't need to check for a node beyond as assigning `nullptr` isn't a problem (I am assuming that an invalid pointer is set to `nullptr` here):

```
{
    while(--index && parent_node->next){     //pre-decrement means we stop before the one we want (parent) 
        parent_node = parent_node->next;}

    if (parent_node->next){node_to_remove= parent_node->next;}
    else {return;}                           //no point deleting it if it doesnt exist
    parent_node->next = node_to_remove->next;//less indirection is always good. Ok if this is nullptr
}
```

Incidentally, this fixes a probable off by one error. Which is probably your problem (did it crash every time? only when deleting the last element? next to last?

Now we just need to delete it.

Putting it all together:

```
void delete_element (Node* &head, int index)
{
    Node* parent_node = head;
    Node* node_to_remove;
    if (index== 0)
    {
        node_to_remove= head;
        head = head->next;
    }
    else
    {
        while(--index && parent_node->next){     //pre-decrement means we stop before the one we want (parent) 
            parent_node = parent_node->next;}

        if (parent_node->next){node_to_remove= parent_node->next;}
        else {return;}                           //no point deleting it if it doesnt exist
        parent_node->next = node_to_remove->next;//less indirection is always good. Ok if this is nullptr
    }
    delete node_to_remove;
    return;
}
```

And that should work fine.  The checks will prevent us dereferencing null pointers which was (probably) what caused you to crash. Can't tell without full code.